# Rails: Stripe Custom Form Won't Submit (Stripe is Double Loaded Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I've been trying for days to implement a custom Stripe form. I've followed many tutorials, and am currently following [Stripe's own tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms) to a T. The error message I receive when trying to submit my form is:

POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens 400 (Bad Request)

When expanded, this shows:

```
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.c @   (index):3
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.e @   (index):3
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.a @   (index):3
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.Stripe.xhr    @   (index):3
Stripe.a._rawRequest    @   (index):2
Stripe.a.request    @   (index):2
Stripe.token.a.create   @   (index):2
Stripe.card.b.createToken   @   (index):2
Stripe.a._channelListener   @   (index):2
Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.H.Socket.t.concat.incoming    @   (index):2
f
```

I'm really stuck at this point so would appreciate any insight!

*orders.new [FORM]*

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">

<label class="form-label" for="number">Card Number</label>
<input type="text" data-stripe="number" />

<label class="form-label" for="cvc">CVC</label>
<input type="text" data-stripe="cvc" />

<label class="form-label">Exp (MM)</label>
<input type="text" data-stripe="exp-month" />

<label class="form-label">Exp (YYYY)</label>
<input type="text" data-stripe="exp-year" />

<button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
```

*orders.js*

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('MY STRIPE TEST KEY');

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

*orders_controller*[relevant part]

```
    begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          :amount      => @amountCents,
          :source => params[:stripeToken],
          :currency    => 'usd')

      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        charge_error = e.message
      end
```

Comment: @Benjamin yep - just posted solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just heard back from Stripe support, and then solution they suggested (which worked!) was to pass the Stripe.card.createToken as an object, rather than form fields. This required adding relevant classes to each form field (see below) and updating the jQuery function.

The updated part of my orders.js now looks like:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('.card-number').val(),
      cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
      exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out too.