# Rails - Stripe Form Not Submitting: 400 (Bad Request) - Stripe is Double Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, stripe-payments

New to rails and trying to create simple order form with stripe and getting this error:

```
(index):3 POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens 400 (Bad       Request)Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.c @ (index):3Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.e @    (index):3Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.a @ (index):3Stripe.isDoubleLoaded.Stripe.xhr @ (index):3Stripe.a._rawRequest @ (index):2Stripe.a.request @ (index):2Stripe.token.a.create @ (index):2Stripe.card.b.createToken @ (index):2Stripe.a._channelListener @ (index):2t.concat.incoming @ (index):2f @   (index):2
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032979/rails-stripe-custom-form-wont-submit-stripe-is-double-loaded-error) post, tried it and had no success.

Here is my orders.js.coffee:

```js
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        Stripe.card.createToken($('#new_order'), payment.handleStripeResponse)
        false

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

Here is my orders form:

```js
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= image_tag @listing.image.url %>
    </div>
    <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
    <h4><%= number_to_currency(@listing.price) %></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |f| %>
      <% if @order.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h3><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h3>

          <ul>
          <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div id="stripe_error" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
        <noscript>
          JavaScript is not enabled and is reqiuered for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.
        </noscript>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :address %>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :city %>
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :state %>
        <%= f.text_field :state, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "number", class: "form-control card-number" } %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= label_tag :card_code, "CVC" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "cvc", class: "form-control card-code" } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag nil, 'Expiration Date' %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
               <%= select_month nil, { use_two_digit_numbers: true }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-month", class: "form-control exp-month" } %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+10 }, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "exp-year", class: "form-control exp-year" } %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Complete Order", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my order controller create method:

```
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)

# Find listing id in url
@listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])

# Seller of a listing is the same as the user who created it
@seller = @listing.user

# Order id is same as the listing id
@order.listing_id = @listing.id

# Buyer Id is equal to current signed in user
@order.buyer_id = current_user.id

# Link order and seller id
@order.seller_id = @seller.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Application layout head:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-    track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name => 'stripe-key', :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
</head>
```

Listings show page button with turbolinks turned off:

```
<div class="center">
      <%= link_to 'Buy It Now', new_listing_order_path(@listing), class: 'btn btn-primary', data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Post complete code of orders form. Are you using form_for?

Comment: I believe you have added js from gem and yourself as well.

Comment: rmn.nish: just added the complete form. Yes using form_for.

Comment: Does this work if you follow the docs here as opposed to using the Rails form helpers? https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form

Comment: do you have turbolinks enabled? I'd try disabling it.